# Getting the error Error:BrokenCount>0 after installing packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I am getting the following error in the top menu bar:

> An error occurred.Please run the Package Manger form the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.The error message was:'Error:BrokenCount>0'.This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Comment: Please open a gnome-terminal, run `sudo apt-get check`, and add the output to your question.

Comment: I typed sudo apt-get check.I got the following:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasound2-plugins : Breaks: libasound2-plugins:i386 (!= 1.0.24-0ubuntu6.1) but 1.0.24-0ubuntu6 is installed
 libasound2-plugins:i386 : Breaks: libasound2-plugins (!= 1.0.24-0ubuntu6) but 1.0.24-0ubuntu6.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: Now try `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: I tried it.nothing happened.I even tried sudo apt-get update.but still no use.

Then i tried sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

It removed all the packages.then i tried sudo apt-get update.After the execution of it, i opened Ubuntu Software Center and clicked repair on the dialog box that appeared.And everything is fine now.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If that fixed your issue, please add it as new answer and accept it by clicking on the checkmark left to the answer (but I think this will only work after a day or two).

Answer (score 2):

I tried

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

To remove all the broken package information.
Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This restored the package database.

After that I opened Ubuntu Software Center and a dialog box appeared saying that i needed to repair some broken dependencies. I clicked on the <kbd>Repair</kbd> button and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Software Center. It may automatically recognize the problem, and ask you for permission to fix it. If so, let it. (That fixed this for me.)