# Apt indicator: 'Error:BrokenCount>0'

Tags: apt, 14.04

I am getting the following error in the top menu bar:

> An error occurred. Please run the Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was:'Error:BrokenCount>0'.

Comment: Did you look into this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068352&page=2

Comment: and this [Getting the error Error:BrokenCount>0 after installing the packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70548/getting-the-error-errorbrokencount0-after-installing-the-packages)

Comment: I'd recommend a merge but the only answer here was already there.

Answer (score 1):

Open software center, a pop up will appear to (auto) repair the problem