# Error: BrokenCount > 0 unable to solve using "sudo apt --fix-broken install"

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, 32-bit

Please note that the answers to these links could not solve my problem:

1. [What does: Error Broken count >0 mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263460/what-does-error-broken-count-0-mean)
2. [Getting the error Error:BrokenCount>0 after installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70548/getting-the-error-errorbrokencount0-after-installing-packages)

[image]

Clicking on the error I get this message:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click
>   menu or apt-get in a teminal to see what is wrong. The error message
>   was :'Error:BrokenCount>0'. This usually means that your installed
>   packages have unment dependences

On running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libfreetype6:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfreetype6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 67 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/351 kB of archives.
After this operation, 972 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 222665 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libfreetype6:i386 (2.8.1-2ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/FTL.TXT.gz', which is different from other instances of package libfreetype6:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I know the problem is this particular line in the above output:

> trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/FTL.TXT.gz',
>   which is different from other instances of package libfreetype6:i386

What do I do to stop trying to override it? Please note that I tried adding `libfreetype6:i386` while experimenting with `wine`. I do not require it and want to remove it. But it seems other packages are dependent on it. 
Running `sudo apt-get autoremove` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcairo2:i386 : Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.7.1) but it is not installed
 libfontconfig1:i386 : Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installed
 libgd3:i386 : Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installed
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It is like being stuck in a deadlock. This dependency  problem  is not letting me install or even upgrade any other application on my system. Please Help!

**Edit:**

Trying `apt-cache policy libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386 libfreetype6:` as suggested in a comment gave:

```
  Installed: 2.8.1-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.8.1-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libfreetype6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.8.1-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.8.1-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: @karel the possible duplicate that you marked has an accepted answer saying "reboot the system". My problem does not get solved by that

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386` to the question.

Comment: I read the accepted answer too, but that's not the answer to that question that I wanted you to read.

Comment: @karel yes the bug mentioned in the top voted answer mentions a `Trolltech.conf` bug very similar to mine (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/1193243) but the workaround it mentions does not work in my case. Please unmark this question as a possible duplicate unless you can tell me what will solve my problem as I really need to solve this problem which is not allowing any other app to get installed on my system!

Comment: I read that answer too. That's not the answer to that question I wanted you to read either. So far you've commented about 2 answers out of 4 answers to that question. The answer that I wanted you to read is one of the other two answers. It's the answer that's similar to N0rbert's answer to this question. That's why I flagged this question as a duplicate question.

Comment: @karel lol ok, but you could have explicitly told me to refer the second answer which had just one upvote. People generally tend to look for higher voted answers. Also N0rbert's answer is better explained than the one in the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your repositories are correct we can simply force installation of the package with:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

And then resume installation with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And for sure get all new dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```